# Posiciones decimales en un array

Tags: java, array

He visto este código y se supone que está bien, no entiendo por qué si por ejemplo "left + right" es un numero impar, al hacer "a[middle] == 0" no da error al no existir en arrays posiciones decimales.

```
/** Busca el valor 0 en a[left..right]. Precondici´on: 0 <= left, right < a.length,
* a[left..right] ordenado ascendentemente. */
public static int intercepts(double[] a, int left, int right) {
    if (left > right) { return -1; }
    else {
        int middle = (left + right) / 2;
        if (a[middle] == 0) { return middle; }
        else if (a[middle] > 0) {
            return intercepts(a, left, middle - 1);
        } else {
            return intercepts(a, middle + 1, right); }
     }
}
```

Comment: Hola, ¿has realizado la prueba de escritorio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Esto es debido a que cuando creas middle lo haces de tipo entero, cuando se le asignen valores, por más que tengan decimales, se truncará.

```
int **ejemplo** = 3/2;
```

En este caso el valor de ejemplo será 1.